# Cumulocity extend API

Tags: cumulocity

We're working with Cumulocity and we'd like to offer services to our customers that are not currently possible to implement with Cumulocity. As an example, we'd like to be able to retrieve a list of devices located within *x* kilometers of a given point.

Currently there are two limitations that prevent us from doing so:

1. the impossibility of extending the Cumulocity API with custom route/parameters
2. the impossibility of implementing custom functions for specific API GET calls

I can think of a workaround to achieve this, like a POST request of an event that would be processed by an Esper rule, generating another event/measurement that could then be accessed by a GET. But I think we can agree this is not a suitable mechanism.

Please not that the use case I described above is just an example. Our needs don't limit to this and we need a standardized way to expand our services without requirering updates on Cumulocity side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two topics here, I believe:

- Geo-querying: Some geographical querying and aggregation use cases can be handled through CEL. A general geo-querying API is on the Cumulocity roadmap. Note: This use case is not only related to extending the API, as such queries go right down into the database.
- Extending the API: That is actually possible. Cumulocity has a microservices API in which you can expose other APIs under the URL /services/.... This is, for example, how connectivity platforms are interfaced. The API is not on the web site because it's not GA yet, but you can certainly discuss it with your Cumulocity contact or open a ticket. This btw includes also adding permissions for the new microservices, so that you can do proper A&A.